# Create simulated hierarchical select box from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a `select` box and show items and their depth with my flat JSON data. Following picture is the same thing that Joomla CMS does in hierarchical categories but using PHP.

[image: Joomla CMS hierarchical categories]

My sample data is like the following (note that depth is infinite):

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "parent": "0",
    "text": "Doctors"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "parent": "0",
    "text": "Clinics"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "parent": 1,
    "text": "General doctors"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "parent": 1,
    "text": "Experts"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "parent": 4,
    "text": "Children diseases specialist"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "parent": 4,
    "text": "Otorhinolaryngology"
}]
```

I wrote the following code and I use it by calling `Data.createTreeOptions(items);` and it's working, but what I get is list of options ordered by original array items. I want items to be loaded in `parent - children` ordering like the ones in picture.

```
var Data = {
    createTreeOptions: function (items) {
        if (!items.length)
            return '';
        var html = '', children = [], l;

        $.each(items, function () {
            l = (typeof children[this.parent] !== "undefined") ? children[this.parent] : [];
            l.push(this);
            children[this.parent] = l;
        });

        var tree = Data.treeRecurse(0, '', [], children, 0);
        $.each(tree, function () {
            if (typeof this.id !== "undefined")
                html += '<option value="' + this.id + '" data-parent="' + this.parent + '">' + this.treemenu + '</option>';
        });
        return html;
    }
    , treeRecurse: function (id, indent, list, children, level) {
        if (typeof children[id] !== "undefined" && children[id]) {
            $.each(children[id], function () {
                var v = this;
                var id = v.id;
                if (v.parent === 0)
                    text = v.text;
                else
                    text = '|_ ' + v.text;

                list[id] = v;
                list[id].treemenu = indent + text;
                list[id].children = (typeof children[id] !== "undefined") ? children[id].length : 0;
                level++;
                list = Data.treeRecurse(id, indent + ' -', list, children, level);
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing to do: open your text editor and start creating the code. Second: show where you stuck. Third: you get one good and accurate answer. The way you asked is really too broad.

Comment: @skobaljic I added my code, I thought I can find better solutions than mine by not showing my own code.

Comment: I do not understand the language, but basically you want to indent the items with `-` for example, based on parent-child relation? that's the main goal?

Comment: @skobaljic Yes, that's exactly the goal. language is not important, these are just text of the `option` elements.

Comment: @skobaljic I updated my `JSON` to show English titles for easier demonstration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case you can create and use jQuery objects this way:

```js
var items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "parent": "0",
    "text": "Doctors"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "parent": "0",
    "text": "Clinics"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "parent": 1,
    "text": "General doctors"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "parent": 1,
    "text": "Experts"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "parent": 4,
    "text": "Children diseases specialist"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "parent": 4,
    "text": "Otorhinolaryngology"
}];
var imagine = $('<div><div class="hierarchy-0"></div></div>');
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
 var parent = imagine.find('.hierarchy-'+item.parent);
    parent.append('<div class="hierarchy-'+item.id+'"><span>'+item.text+'</span></div>');
});
function findChildren(elem, indent) {
    elem.children('div').each(function(c, child) {
        selectHtml += '<option>'+'-'.repeat(indent)+$(child).children('span').text()+'</option>';
        findChildren($(child), indent+1);
    });
};
var selectHtml = '';
findChildren(imagine.find('.hierarchy-0'), 0);
$('select').html( selectHtml );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1a0pbrg/).

But, I am sure you will get another, better approach :)

Comment: Creating an imaginary div and then using it to generate options seems to be working! I was trying to do the same thing with JS but without "imagination"!

Answer (score -2):

You can do this simply with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="1">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>


<script>

   var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
   for(var i in myJSON){
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = myJSON[i].text;
     x.add(option);
   }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if you want to modify the size of the select use size attribute.

Comment: Where are you ordering items by their parents to do what I want?

Comment: I didn't understand your question sorry, you have a parent attribute in your json do you want to add the option based on the number of the parent? Or you can explain me better your parent children relation?